# Printing In Landscape mode from a WebBrowser control?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, printing, webbrowser-control

```
System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser wb = new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser();

wb.DocumentStream = new FileStream("C:\a.html", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
while (wb.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
{
    Application.DoEvents();
}
wb.Print();
```

I know how to set the page orientation from a PrinterDocument object, but not from a WebBrowser object.  Any way to do this?  Thanks!

Comment: I'm confused?  The title says from a web browser control but then you say not from a web browser object in your question. Which is it?

Comment: I think someone edited my question to say it's a control.  Just refer to the code example, that is the exact code I'm using now and am hoping to learn how to print in landscape mode from.

Comment: @sooprise You want to keep this under the covers or is user interaction acceptable?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "user interaction"? I don't follow, thanks.

Comment: Aaron means, I guess, - do you want to display printing dialog or don't?

Comment: The printing dialog is not necessary

Comment: When I tried, I was unsuccessful in getting the WebBrowser object to print in landscape. I'm not sure it it's capable of doing that. I'm happy to see the reference to mshtml.dll.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, I recommend you to use async event model:

```
wb.DocumentCompleted += wb_DocumentCompleted;

private void wb_DocumentCompleted (object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    ((WebBrowser)sender).Print();
}
```

To print (add the reference to `Microsoft.mshtml.dll`):

```
mshtml.IHTMLDocument2 doc = wb.Document.DomDocument as mshtml.IHTMLDocument2;
doc.execCommand("print", showUI, templatePath);
```

See [IHTMLDocument2.execCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752577%28VS.85%29.aspx), [MSDN forum question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/e3aab4dd-125d-4c2f-98ac-3f0f25d357f2) and follow links.

Comment: That is much easier and is more efficient, thanks.  I just implemented it.

Comment: @sooprise: I have some experience with WB control and looking for changing printing page position. I'll give you know if will find something interesting

Comment: mshtml.IHTMLDocument2 doc = wb.Document as mshtml.IHTMLDocument2; <- This line of code doesn't appear to work...